# I would like to get the records related to text by DQL

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, doctrine-query

DATABASE:

```
id | name     | // ...
====================
1  | London   |
2  | Paris    |
3  | Moscow   |
4  | New York |

// ...
```

TEXT:

```
This is a big city. I live in this town.
I like the name of city. 'New York' is very cool.
However, I have to go to Moscow this summer.
// ...
```

There are a lot of records in the database.
Text is written in various languages​​.

I would like to get the records related to text.
In this case, I would like to get the records of 'New York' and 'Moscow'.

I am using a Doctrine2 ORM and DQL.
And my database is usually mysql.

Is it possible to achieve this by using the DQL?

---

#### UPDATE

City Entity : id, name, population date_created etc...

```
id | name     | population | // ...
====================================
1  | London   | 1,2448,3938| 
2  | Paris    | 1,8759,4844|
3  | Moscow   |12,8450,3748|
4  | New York | 8,4795,8558|

// ...
```

Article Entity : id, body, author, date_created etc...

```
id | body                                        | // ...
============================================================
1  | This is a big city. I live in this town.    |
   | I like the name of city.                    |
   | 'New York' is very cool.                    |
   | However, I have to go to Moscow this summer.|
   | // ...                                      | 
2  | We bought a house in London.  //...         |
3  | I go to Canada this weekend.  //...         |
4  | Weather in Africa today is too bad. //...   |

// ...
```

The text is good whether it get from a file or a database.

```
public function findOneById($id)
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
        SELECT a, u
        FROM MyArticleBundle:Article a
        LEFT JOIN a.author u
        WHERE a.id = :id
    ')
    ->setParameter('id', $id);

    return $this->try_catch($query);
}

or

$article = file_get_contents('example.txt');
```

And I bring it to the display.

```
{{ article }} or {{ article.body }} etc...
```

At this time, how do I get the city data of related to this article?
Is it'll need a complex database configuration?

The text and entity (in this case 'city' data) has no association.
Is it possible that I get the data that appears in the text or strings?

such as : `SELECT c FROM MyExampleBundle:City c WHERE c.name appear in ({$text});`

Although I know the example is impossible, but I wanted to know whether there is a way to easily get like a that in DQL.

Comment: Do you want to get the records where the `name` or `text` field contains 'New York' and 'Moscow'? Please add more information about your entity, we can't build a query without the name of the entity.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I added the description above.

Comment: Is the first part of your question still unanswered? I suggest to move the last question to a new question. And it's hard to answer to the last question without information about how the entities are associated.

Comment: Sorry my english and I can't figure out now if it will need a complex configuration of database. My question is simple. The text and entity (in this case 'city' data) has no association. Is it possible that I get the data that appears in the text or strings?
such as : `where city.name in ({$text})`. Although I know the example is impossible, but I wanted to know whether there is a way to easily get like a that in DQL.

Comment: Please read your question again, it's hard to understand what is the point of your question. See the [doctrine2 documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) about association to associate your two entities.

Answer (score 0):

*In this case, I would like to get the records of 'New York' and 'Moscow'.*

So you need to use the [`like()` function](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods) with the `%` character. The `%` will act as a wildcard, for example `A%` will select every row where the selected field starts with `A`. And `%A%` will select every row which contains `A`.

```php
public function findArticlesFromTowns($town_1, $town_2)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');

    $buffer = $qb
        ->select('a, u')
        ->leftJoin('a.author', 'u')
        ->where(
            $qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->like('a.body',
                    $qb->expr()->literal('%'.$town_1.'%')),
                $qb->expr()->like('a.body',
                    $qb->expr()->literal('%'.$town_2.'%'))
            )
        )
    ;

    $q = $buffer->getQuery();

    return $q->getResult();
}
```

`$town_1` and `$town_2` are *New York* and *Moscow* respectively. By using `andX()` the query will select all the rows where the `body` field contains *New York* **and** *Moscow*.

Comment: No no no... my english is too bad? uh... in this case, I do not know where the city is included in the text. My request the point is that I would like to get the city data that appear in the text that I don't know the content. This is an image : `SELECT c FROM MyExampleBundle:City c WHERE c.name appear in ({$text});`

Comment: The position of the towns names is not a problem, the query will fetch the rows which *contains* the towns names, they can be anywhere in the text.

Comment: Your answer is I know what the city name is included in the text. I can do it if such is the case. I don't want to get the article data that contain the specific city name. I'd like to get the city data that the name of the city is included in the text. I don't know the content of text. I don't know which city name included to the text.

Comment: I quoted a sentence from your question and I think that my answer is correct. Why ask for *New York* and *Moscow* if you don't know the city names?